# LU Decomp without pivoting in Python

Tags: python, decomposition

I need to create the function `[L,U] = lr(A)` which will compute the LU decomp of matrix A without pivoting or the use of `inv`,`lu`,etc to solve the linear equation.

Just trying to work out the pseudo-code for now and understand it. Any ideas on how to get started?

Comment: First google result for "LU decomposition python" https://www.quantstart.com/articles/LU-Decomposition-in-Python-and-NumPy It uses numpy so if you need inspiration you can read the source for `numpy.linalg.lu`

Comment: I understand the process mathematically and can do it by hand, but I'm not sure how to avoid pivoting and get the same result

Comment: Does the numpy implementation use pivoting?

Comment: it doesn't, but I am not allowed to use the built in function lu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Numerical Methods in Engineering with Python 3" by Kiusalaas is a great resource. Below is the code for Doolittle's decomposition method from the book.

```
# [L][U] = LUdecomp([A])
def LUdecomp(a):
    n = len(a)
    for k in range(0,n-1):
        for i in range(k+1,n):
            if a[i,k] != 0.0:
                lam = a [i,k]/a[k,k]
                a[i,k+1:n] = a[i,k+1:n] - lam*a[k,k+1:n]
                a[i,k] = lam
    return a
```